# ViewCompat.animate - how to restore view on animation end?

Tags: android, animation, view

With the new ViewCompat.animate there is no such thing as setFillAfter(false) - it seems to be default set to true as the view isn't restored once the animation has finished. Anyone knows how to fix this so I can get my view state restored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setFillAFter` is from the old animation system that was only applying a Matrix to the view canvas and removing the matrix or not at the end. The new animation system is actually physically changing the view itself.

Said that, if you want to revert the animation at the end of it, you have to use an Runnable to execute at the end of the animation. Something like that:

(example if you're animating X value)

```
final float initialValue = ViewCompat.getX(view);
... do your animation code
.withEndAction(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ViewCompat.setX(view, initialValue);
    }
};)
```

Comment: Ok so what you say is I manually have to restore every changed property at the end of the animation. Just as I expected - but good to hear it from someone else :)